# Subgroup element composition

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Please validate the following proof.

---

Let $H$ be a subgroup of the Abelian group $G$ with elements $h \in H$ and $g \in G$ but $g \notin H$.

**Theorem**

The product $gh \notin H$.

**Proof**

Let $x = gh$. Assume $x \in H$, then by multiplying by $h^{-1} \in H$ we have that $xh^{-1} = gh(h^{-1}) = g(h h^{-1}) = g$. So we have composed two elements of $H$ and obtained an element $g \notin H$ and this violates the closure of the subgroup, hence $gh \notin H$. $\square$

Comment: Seems good. The abelian hypothesis is not needed

Comment: Thank you. If you can provide proof (in an answer) of your assertion that this is true for non-Abelian groups too, then I will accept it.

Comment: where did you use that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: Right-multiplying by $h^{-1}$ rather than multiplying on the left.

Comment: You can multiply on the right or the left however you wish regardless of whether the group is abelian. Whether the group is abelian will only affect the outcome of the multiplication. You have $x=gh$ and you multiplied $x$ on the right by $h^{-1}$ (which you can do in an group). The outcome of this multiplication is $g$ (which is true regardless of whether $G$ is abelian). So your proof is complete and correct, and does not use the assumption that $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypothesis: $H\leq G, g\in G-H, h\in H$.

Suppose that $gh\in H$ and we will have a contradiction/

Since $h\in H$ and $H$ is a subgroup we have $h^{-1}\in H$.

Since $h^{-1}, gh\in H \Rightarrow (gh)\cdot h^{-1}=g\in H$ contradiction.

I used that fact that "if $a,b\in H\leq G$ then $ab,ba\in H$"

Comment: Can you show that $ab,ba \in H$

Comment: Do you agree that if $a,b\in H$ then $ab\in H$?

Comment: Yes, but for non-Abelian groups, there must be proof that $h^{-1}gh \notin H$.

Comment: If you agree that $a,b\in H \Rightarrow ab\in H$ then you will agree that $a,b\in H \Rightarrow b,a\in H \Rightarrow ba\in H$

Comment: Thank you. While preparing a [second question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851179/non-abelian-subgroup-element-composition) I see now that it is true for the non-Abelian case too. I will post the question anyway for my own future reference.

Answer (score 2):

In fact

> If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $h \in H$, then for all $g \in G$ we have $gh \in H \iff g \in H$.

Indeed, $gh \in H \implies g \in Hh^{-1} \subseteq H$.
Conversely, $g \in H \implies gh \in H$. Both claims follow because $H$ is a subgroup and so is closed under products and inverses.

Comment: Is there a proof?

Comment: @conchild, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Or you could say you have shown $g\in H$.  Either way, contradiction.  That completes the proof.

Comment: The theorem is that $g \notin H$.

Comment: The _assumption_ is that $g\not\in H$.  The conclusion is that $gh\not\in H$.