# Non-Abelian subgroup element composition

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of the non-Abelian group $G$ with elements $h \in H$ and $g \in G$ but $g \notin H$.

It is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851128/subgroup-element-composition) for the Abelian case that the product $gh \notin H$. To prove the non-Abelian case we need to establish that both $gh \notin H$ and also $hg \notin H$.

Working through the proof for the non-Abelian case we obtain $x=hgh^{-1}$ and it is not clear that $x \notin H$.

How do complete the proof for the non-Abelian case? An alternative proof strategy will be accepted.

Comment: Not following.  If $gh_1=h_2$ then $g=h_2h_1^{-1}\in H$.  If $h_1g=h_2$ then $g=h_1^{-1}h_2\in H$.

Comment: This is not the case because $g \notin H$.

Comment: That's the point.  We have a contradiction, which means that our premise , $gh_1\in H$, must have been false.

Comment: Several comments in the question you link explicitly discuss the fact that your proof there worked in the non-abelian case.

Comment: This question is about a *proof* of the non-Abelian case. It must be shown that $gh \notin H$ and $hg \notin H$. Both are required.

Comment: Ok, but both are trivial.  I did them both in my first comment.  As others have remarked, there is no meaningful difference between the abelian and non-abelian cases.

Comment: @conchild Your same proof from the other question still works. In the $hg$ case, just do the exact same proof but multiply on the left by $h^{-1}$ instead, not the right.

Comment: In this case, it would be better to edit your first question and note that the same arguments work when $G$ is non-abelian. This is preferable to creating two different questions that are very nearly identical.

Comment: I have answered the question myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the Abelian and non Abelian case. Suppose $g\in G$ and $h\in H$. If
$$
gh=x\in H
$$
then $g=xh^{-1}\in H$.

Similarly, if $hg=y\in H$, then $g=h^{-1}y\in H$.

Comment: The question is about $g \notin H \implies x \notin H$.

Comment: @conchild I proved that if $gh\in H$ or $hg\in H$, then $g\in H$. Isn't it sufficient?

Comment: I am not convinced.

Comment: @conchild You want to prove: “for all $g\in G$, $h\in H$, if $g\notin H$, then $gh\notin H$ and $hg\notin H$”. I proved the contrapositive: “for all $g\in G$, $h\in H$, if $gh\in H$ or $hg\in H$, then $g\in H$”.